# $A, B$ are matrices from $M_4(\mathbb R)$ so that $AB=BA$ and $\det(A^2-AB+B^2)=0$.

Tags: matrices, contest-math

> Prove that, if $A, B$ are matrices from $M_4(\Bbb R)$ so that $AB=BA$  and $\det(A^2 −AB + B^2) = 0$ then:
> $$
> \det(A + B) + 3\det(A − B) = 6 (\det(A) + \det(B)). \tag 1
> $$

**What I tried:**

Because of $AB=BA$ we can use, let's say, the Newton's binomial expansion for $A$ and $B$, but it didn't take me to the solution.

Also it's easy to show that $\det (A^3 + B^3) = 0$.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ commute. So if they are diagonalizable, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. IIRC the same applies to their Jordan blocks, if they happen to not be diagonalizable. Therefore it seems to me that we can as well assume that $A$ and $B$ are diagonal. In that case we have simply an identity of quartic polynomials with 4+4 variables (together with that constraint).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it certainly suffices to prove this in the diagonalizable case, since we can always extend to the non-diagonalizable case using the continuity of the determinant.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Interesting, but can we use "elementary" knowledge?

Comment: Note: taking $A = I, B = -I$, we see that it is not sufficient to have $\det(A^3 + B^3) = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Doesn't satisfy : $\det(A^2 −AB + B^2) = 0$

Comment: @EugenCovaci exactly, but it does satisfy $\det(A^3 + B^3) = 0$, so obviously the fact given is significant on its own.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes because $A + B = 0$, not because: $ \det(A^2 −AB + B^2) = 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Again, $\det(A^2 −AB + B^2) \not= 0$

Comment: The claim does not hold for complex matrices. It is essential that $A$ and $B$ are real. $A=I_4$, $B=diag(e^{\pi i/3},1,1,1)$ is a complex counterexample. We can make $B$ similar to a real matrix by using $e^{-\pi i/3}$ as some other diagonal entry, but then .... THE IDENTITY HOLDS! Trying to turn this into a solution...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a third root of unity. Since $A$ and $B$ commute, the condition that $\det(A^2-AB+B^2)=0$ becomes
$$\det(A+\omega B)\det(A+\omega^2 B)=0$$
and so either $\det(A+\omega B)=0$ or $\det(A+\omega^2 B)=0$.

Now consider the function $p(x)=\det(A+xB)$. This is a polynomial of degree at most $4$ with real coefficients, and from the above we see that either $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ is a root of $p$. Since $p$ has real coefficients, we then see that in fact **both** $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are roots of $p$, and that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of $p$.

Let $p(x)=(x^2+x+1)q(x)$ where $q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$, and let $q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are some real numbers.

Now consider the polynomial $r(x)=\det(xA+B)$.

For any $x\neq 0$, we have that

$$r(x)=\det\left(xA+B\right)=\det\left(x\left(A + \frac{1}{x}B\right)\right) = x^4\det\left(A + \frac{1}{x}B\right) = x^4p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Then we have that
$$r(x)=x^4\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)\left(\frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{b}{x}+c\right)=(x^2+x+1)(a+bx+cx^2)$$
for any $x\neq 0$. The left and right hand sides of this expression are polynomials which agree at every point except possibly $x=0$, and so they must in fact be equal for all real $x$, including $x=0$. We see that

$$\det(B)=r(0)=a$$

Now we note that

$$\det(A+B)+3\det(A-B)=p(1)+3p(-1)=3q(1)+3q(-1)$$

which is equal to

$$6(a+c) = 6(\det(B)+q(0))=6(\det(B)+p(0))=6(\det(B)+\det(A))$$

as required.